# Sql Server 2008 Express with full text search

Tags: full-text-search, sql-server-express

I wanted to try out the fts feature of sql server 2008 express. According to the product page (http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx) , there should be fts included in the download.

> Offers reporting capabilities, full-text search, and spatial support

The download i get is SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe, 260 megs in size, and when i run the installer, there is no mention of fts. Still i try install it with all features (Select All), and when the install is done, i test to create a fts catalog. The catalog is created but when i try to edit and add tables, i get errors.

> Property IsAccentSensitive is not available for FullTextCatalog '[CatalogName]'

and

> Property PopulationStatus is not available for FullTextCatalog

These errors indicate that full text search has NOT been installed. ([Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2131/property-populationstatus-is-not-available-for-fulltextcatalog-how-to-fix))

Now, i also read on the above stackexchange question that the installer that includes fts is larger than 200 megs, it should be like 800 megs, so that is another clue that my installer does not contain fts. Not only that but the link in the above question is redirected to the product page linked first in my question.

Does anyone know how to get the express version WITH full text search?

Answer (score 5):

You have to install SQL Server Express With Advanced Services in order to get Full Text Search functionality.
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=25174

Answer (score 1):

You might try this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910067